# Keeping freebsd up to date with only binary packages

Tags: freebsd

Here's what I want: I want to install RELEASE-8.2, and want to keep the system and packages up to date with security patches only. I want to avoid ports b/c I do not want my machines to start compiling large packages and their dependencies when it has a high load; also, I do not want to deal with broken ports.

Keeping the core system seems simple enough with `freebsd-update fetch` and `freebsd-update install`.

How should I keep packages up to date with the latest available from `ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-8.1-release/Latest/`?  The `portupgrade` man page says that the `-PP` flag may be what I want-- however, it says I need an updated ports tree.  That's fine, but what happens if I have Foo-1.0 installed, the ports tree says Foo-1.2 is the newest version, but only Foo-1.1 is available as a package? Will it recognize Foo-1.1 as a higher version? If so, why does it need an updated ports tree?

Is this enough?:

```
portsnap fetch update
portupgrade -a -PP
```

(I'm assuming you don't need `-r` or `-R` when you have `-a`, right?)

Comment: Running just those commands you'll end up with a ton of "package not found" errors as Foo-1.2 will commonly not be available.

Comment: This happens because the updated ports collection is looking for packages from either STABLE or CURRENT (I think it's STABLE), but portupgrade is using the PACKAGESITE for 8.1-release, so it finds the older packages. If he changes the PACKAGESITE url to `ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-8-stable/All/` and runs the commands, it will upgrade the packages to match the updated ports collection, but he'll no longer be following RELEASE, instead STABLE. In a nutshell, to get the latest binary packaes, you need to change the repo from RELEASE to STABLE or CURRENT.

Comment: You might want to throw a `pkgdb -F` in there before running portupgrade, just as a precaution.

Comment: Just as a note, `-a` makes portupgrade check all packages, but it won't upgrade dependencies/dependents without the appropriate `-r` or `-R` flags.  Not sure about upgrading with packages, but you may need to upgrade like a pirate (`-arR`) to cover all the bases...

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the workings of portupgrade, it uses the ports tree (specifically, the index) to populate its own database of available ports and determine which installed packages are out of date. I have not personally tried using it with binary packages, but I suspect that in the case of an available package being older than the in-tree port, portupgrade would not find the package.

Comment: Your understanding is essentially correct: `-PP` will work if it can find the appropriate version of a package (matching the version in the local ports tree) on the server.  If not it will complain that it couldn't find a package.